# How to determine if a computer in my Windows Domain is "active"

Tags: c#, exception, networking, dns, ping

I'm trying to write a method that will determine which computers in my domain are "inactive." The only way I have been able to get this to work is by trying to get the IP address of the computer by using:

`Dns.GetHostAddresses( computerName )`

If the computer is "inactive" it throws a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` which I am then able to catch and add that computer to my DataTable of inactive computers. The problem with this method is that it is PAINFULLY slow. Going through my Windows domain with 500 computers about 300 are "inactive" and it takes almost 30 minutes to sort them by this method. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to tell if a computer registered in my Windows domain is active?

I have also tried to do this by pinging all the computers in my list, but when trying to ping an "inactive" computer is throws a `System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException` which I have to catch and handle the same way. This also gives me a nearly 30 minute run-time for this process.

Here is my code.

```
public void findInactiveComputers( string customerName, string domain )
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry( domain );
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher( entry );
            searcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
            searcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
            searcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

            // Removes the inactive computers from the DataTable that associated with the customer.
            if( _InactiveComputers.Rows.Count != 0 )
            {
                _InactiveComputers.AsEnumerable().Where( cust => cust["CustomerName"].ToString()
                    .Equals( customerName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) )
                    .ToList().ForEach( comp => comp.Delete() );
            }

            foreach( SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll() )
            {
                if( result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.StartsWith( "CN=" ) )
                {
                    string computerName = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.Remove( 0, "CN=".Length );

                    try
                    { 
                        Dns.GetHostAddresses( computerName );
                    }

                    catch( SocketException )
                    {
                        DataRow newRow = _InactiveComputers.NewRow();
                        newRow["ComputerName"] = computerName;
                        newRow["CustomerName"] = customerName;
                        _InactiveComputers.Rows.Add( newRow );
                    }
                }
            }

            Properties.Settings.Default.InvalidComputers = _InactiveComputers;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

EDIT:

I tried to use multiple threads to accomplish my task, but the wait time is still very long (I'm running it now and it still hasn't completed).

Here's how I implemented it, suggestions to improve performance?

```
List<string> inactiveComputerNames = new List<string>();

            foreach( SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll() )
            {
                new Thread( delegate()
                    {
                        if( result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.StartsWith( "CN=" ) )
                        {
                            string computerName = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.Remove( 0, "CN=".Length );

                            try
                            {
                                Dns.GetHostAddresses( computerName );
                            }

                            catch( SocketException )
                            {
                                inactiveComputerNames.Add( computerName );
                            }
                        }
                    } ).Start();
            }

            foreach( string computerName in inactiveComputerNames )
            {
                DataRow newRow = _InactiveComputers.NewRow();
                newRow["ComputerName"] = computerName;
                newRow["CustomerName"] = customerName;
                _InactiveComputers.Rows.Add( newRow );
            }
```

Comment: any reason you are running this sequentially instead of using multiple threads ?

Comment: Inactive as in "not responding to network requests"?

Comment: Inactive as in a machine that no longer exists, but was there before and shows up because of that fact.

Comment: Yahia, I am only not using multiple threads, because of the inconvenience of it. I was hoping there was a cleaner way to handle the problem without catching exceptions.

Comment: Your threaded version could use some locking around accesses to the List. You may also want to consider rate limiting so as to avoid the situation where you end up with 500 in-flight threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out this issue...Finally! I used a `Parallel.ForEach` Loop and it solved all my problems. I had to use locking around the access to the List as sixlettervariables suggested. Worked great!

```
SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();

            List<string> inactiveComputerNames = new List<string>();

            object threadLock = new object();

            Parallel.ForEach( results.OfType<SearchResult>(), result =>
            {
                if( result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.StartsWith( "CN=" ) )
                {
                    string computerName = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.Remove( 0, "CN=".Length );

                    try
                    {
                        Dns.GetHostAddresses( computerName );
                    }

                    catch( SocketException )
                    {
                        lock( threadLock )
                        {
                            inactiveComputerNames.Add( computerName );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement in that I wanted to scan a network for IP addresses to determine the addresses in use.

I made several assumptions, firstly that the Ping would not be blocked on the majority of equipment, secondly that we were only dealing with a specific range of addresses EG 192.168.x.x

It's not the cleanest of code, just a quick and dirty example but the following will run as a console app and demonstrates the basic principles of how you could use threading in conjunction with Ping.

Hope it helps?

Kind Regards, Wayne

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NetworkPing
{
    class Program
    {

        private static int _Timeout = 120;
        private static int nextLine = 0;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NetworkPing!");

            //check if any command line arguments have been supplied
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                //parse the the arguments
                foreach ( string arg in args)
                {
                    switch( arg[1].ToString() )
                    {
                        case "?":
                            {
                                //display help topic
                                DisplayHelp();
                            }
                        break;

                        case "t":
                            {
                                //change the timout
                                _Timeout = Int32.Parse( GetParameter(arg) );
                                Console.WriteLine("Ping timeout set to {0}ms", _Timeout);
                            }
                        break;
                    }    
                }
            }


            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

            IPAddress[] Adresses2 = GetAllUnicastAddresses();
            foreach (IPAddress Adres in Adresses2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Local IP Address: {0}", Adres);
                Console.WriteLine("Scanning IP from {0}.1 to {0}.254, awaiting results...", NetworkAddress(Adres) );

                nextLine = Console.CursorTop;

                Task[] tasks = new Task[254];

                for (int i = 0; i != 254; i++)
                {
                    //calculate the IP address for the ping
                    string ipAddressToPing = NetworkAddress( Adres ) + "." + (i+1);
                    //ping the address and check the response
                    tasks[ i ] = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => PingAddress(ipAddressToPing) );
                }

                //Block until all tasks complete.
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            }

            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            Console.WriteLine("");            
            Console.WriteLine("Scan complete in {0} seconds, Press any key to continue...", ts.Seconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string GetParameter( string Argument )
        {
            return Argument.Substring( Argument.LastIndexOf(":") +1);
        }

        public static void DisplayHelp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: PingNetwork [/?] or [-?] [-t:Timeout]");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0,-12} {1}","/?","Display these usage instructions");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0,-12} {1}","-?","Display these usage instructions");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0,-12} {1}","-t:timeout","Changes the default timout from 120ms");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public static IPAddress[] GetAllUnicastAddresses()
        {
            // This works on both Mono and .NET , but there is a difference: it also
            // includes the LocalLoopBack so we need to filter that one out
            List<IPAddress> Addresses = new List<IPAddress>();
            // Obtain a reference to all network interfaces in the machine
            NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
                foreach (IPAddressInformation uniCast in properties.UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    // Ignore loop-back, IPv6 and link-local
                    if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily!= AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 && !uniCast.Address.ToString().StartsWith("169.254.") )
                        Addresses.Add(uniCast.Address);
                }

            }
            return Addresses.ToArray();
        }

        private static void PingAddress( string IPAddress )
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            options.DontFragment = true;

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);

            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(IPAddress, _Timeout, buffer, options);

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                   //set the cursor to the next line
                Console.CursorTop = nextLine;
                //        
                Console.WriteLine( IPAddress + " :OK");
                //
                nextLine++;
            }
        }


        private static string NetworkAddress( IPAddress Address )
        {
            string ipAddress = Address.ToString();
            return ipAddress.Substring( 0, ipAddress.LastIndexOf(".") );
        }

        private static string LastOctet( IPAddress Address )
        {
            string ipAddress = Address.ToString();
            return ipAddress.Substring( ipAddress.LastIndexOf(".") );
        }

        private static int _cursorX;
        private static int _cursorY;

        private static void GetCursor()
        {
            _cursorX = Console.CursorLeft;
            _cursorY = Console.CursorTop;
        }

        private static void SetCursor()
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = _cursorX;
            Console.CursorTop = _cursorY;
        }

    }
}
```